# Estimate of threshold values for 7-qubit Steane code with qiskit (or stim)

Tags: qiskit, error-correction, stabilizer-code, stim, fault-tolerance

I have trouble recreating the graphs shown in this paper
https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0508176.pdf
i.e. the quadratic trend of the logical error against physical single qubit error for [7,1,3] code

I attempted to do the simplest case, the logical error rate graph for a transversal H gate and wrote the following piece of quantum circuit with qiskit,

```
 lz = ['0000000', '1010101', '1100110', '0110011',
      '1111000', '0101101', '0011110', '1001011']

for ind, pi in enumerate(p):
    error_1 = noise.depolarizing_error(4 * pi / 3, 1)
    error_2 = noise.depolarizing_error(16 * pi / 15, 2)
    nm = noise.NoiseModel()
    nm.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_1, ['id', 'h'])

    s = 0
    fid = 0
    for i in tqdm(range(n)):
        lq = QuantumRegister(7)
        x_anc = QuantumRegister(3)
        z_anc = QuantumRegister(3)
        x_syn = ClassicalRegister(3)
        z_syn = ClassicalRegister(3)
        qc = QuantumCircuit(x_anc, z_anc, lq, x_syn, z_syn)

        # prepare a logical 0 state as in [AGP05][1]
        perf_qc_0(qc, lq)
        # to compute threshold of transversal H gate
        qc.h(lq)

        EC(qc, x_anc, z_anc, lq, x_syn, z_syn)

        # append a noiseless transversal H as reverse operation
        qc.append(h_nl, [lq])
        qc.measure_all()

        run = backend.run(qc, noise_model=nm, shots=1).result() #
        mmt = list(run.get_counts().keys())[0]

        # if measurement returns to space spanned by logical 0 components, accept
        if (mmt[:7] in lz):
            s += 1

    le[ind] = 1-s/n
    print("logical error rate is {}".format(le[ind]))
```

The error correction gadget I have is

```
def EC(qc, x_anc, z_anc, lq, x_syn, z_syn):
# Syndrome measurements
qc.h(x_anc)
qc.h(z_anc)

qc.cx(z_anc[2], [lq[i - 1] for i in [4, 5, 6, 7]])
qc.cx(z_anc[1], [lq[i - 1] for i in [2, 3, 6, 7]])
qc.cx(z_anc[0], [lq[i - 1] for i in [1, 3, 5, 7]])

qc.cz(x_anc[2], [lq[i - 1] for i in [4, 5, 6, 7]])
qc.cz(x_anc[1], [lq[i - 1] for i in [2, 3, 6, 7]])
qc.cz(x_anc[0], [lq[i - 1] for i in [1, 3, 5, 7]])

qc.h(x_anc)
qc.h(z_anc)
qc.measure(x_anc, x_syn)
qc.measure(z_anc, z_syn)

# Apply correction X gates
for i in range(1,8):
    qc.x(lq[i-1]).c_if(x_syn, i)

# Apply correction Z gates
for i in range(1,8):
    qc.z(lq[i-1]).c_if(z_syn, i)
```

The graph I obtain is more of a linear trend for some reason ...

I must have done something wrong but I can't see where. I'm still quite new to QECC so thanks if you can help!!

Update: I found that Stim is a library specifically for QECC, however I'm not sure how to implement Steane code with correct decoder in pymatching. Anyone can help?

Comment: where have you built in an error correcting code and error correction?

Comment: @DaftWullie Hi I updated my question. I did the simplest Steane syndrome extraction, as in Fig1 of the paper [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.05647.pdf). But it's still not the trend expected. What exactly should I do to obtain the corresponding graphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue you are running into is that the construction used in that paper, which they say comes from [this other paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0406025), is not just a [[7,1,3]] code. It's a [[7,1,3]] code concatenated some number of times, with a special rule of some sort for redoing the stabilizer measurements if errors are detected in the lower levels.

If you put circuit noise into a normal [[7,1,3]] circuit, as it measures its stabilizers, there are error locations that cause a logical error with no symptoms. This is probably why yours isn't working: you're bounded by those errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try to implement the construction. As these are some papers 2 decades ago, what structure do people nowadays use for fault-tolerant Steane code? Would you maybe name a few papers?
And also ... I wonder how people used to generate these graphs so smoothly back in the day without the current simulators

Comment: @AndyLiuin I wrote this blog post recently that covers various ways of doing fault-tolerant measurements. https://abdullahkhalid.com/blog/2022/Oct/26/fault-tolerant-syndrome-measurements/

Comment: @AbdullahKhalid Thanks! I've just read it. Could I ask, were you able to generate the quadratic graph of logical error vs physical error and deduce the threshold with this cat state EC?